# Django - deleted object using .delete() method and now getting Exception Type: IntegrityError

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, foreign-keys

I created a learning log blog by following Python Crash Course and I noticed that there were some topics that I did not need.  So I used the learning_log.objects.filter(id=id number).delete() in the python manage.py shell to delete some duplicate items.  I then tried to add new topics and received this error:

IntegrityError at /new_topic/
NOT NULL constraint failed: learning_logs_topic.owner_id

In the models.py file, I have tried passing default='' to text = models.TextField(), passing null=True,blank=True to the models.TextField, running manage.py makemigrations --fake and rerunning makemigrations/migrate.  But nothing seems to fix this issue.   I am trying to avoid deleting my database and starting over, but I think that might be the only solution.

*UPDATE

Read through the ForeignKey documentation and replaced "on_delete=models.CASCADE" with "models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,", reran the migrations and now can successfully add more topics/entries.

```
Models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=" ")
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returning a string represetation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) #added after deleting topic and getting error
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of model"""
        if len(self.text) > 50:
            return self.text[:50] + '...'
        else:
            return self.text
```

```
Views.py
def index(request):
    '''The home page for Learning Log'''
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    """Show all topics"""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    '''Show all topics and all its entries.'''
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')    
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

def new_topic(request):
    '''Add a new topic'''
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted, create a blank form
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted, processes data
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)
```

```
new_topic.html
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Add a topic:</p>
    <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}"method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button name="submit"> add topic</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

The expected result is to click "Add a new topic", enter topic into text field, click add topic and the be returned to Topics page with the recently added topic in list.

Comment: The owner fk needs a value when you create a topic

Comment: isn't the value for a topic generated with the id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) in the Topic class in Models.py?